# SyntaxError:InvalidSyntax?

Tags: python, django

I followed http://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html in order to add a user authentication in my Django project but when I migrate an error occured in my project urls.py but I didn't find it !!!
newsite/newsite/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from aps import views
from mail import views
from log import views
from django.contrib.auth import views
from log.forms import LoginForm

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),    
url(r'^aps/', include('aps.urls')),
url(r'^mail/', include('mail.urls')),
url(r'^log/', include('log.urls')),
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm},
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout, {'next_page': '/login'}), 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the last `)`.

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html', 'authentication_form': LoginForm}),
```

Comment: oh thannks , I wasn't in my mood while writing :)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest you go back to the link that you provided as your source. You've miscopied some of the code. For example this line from the example provided:

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

You did not provide the error message/trace you received, so of the couple of problems it could be, its impossible to say which one is giving you the error you are currently receiving -- but again, compare your code to the example for errors (including in indentation). If it still doesn't work, provide the error message you receive

Comment: Thank you  I've missed a ) :)